# Your kittens return empty-pawed

Tags: kittens-game

Usually I see "Zebras hate you for no reason" if trading with zebras fails, but sometimes I see "Your kittens return empty-pawed".

What is the difference?

---

Saw it again:

```
Year 490, Summer: Your kittens return empty-pawed
Year 490, Summer: You have sent 2 trade caravans
```

I was not full on either iron or titanium.

Comment: There just isn't any resource that you obtained during the trade, but no clue how this can occur. Aren't your stocks full or anything?

Comment: Was that really a zebra trade? That message should only show up for dragons and leviathans.

Comment: Yep, it was a zebra trade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code of the game, it seems that you will only receive the "[Race] hate you for no reason" message for single trade missions, while you will receive the "Your kittens return empty-pawed" message if you send multiple trade missions at once and they all fail, e.g. from hostile relations, or failed trade chances from Dragons or Leviathans.

---

On a more technical level...

Four functions are of particular significance here: `trade`, `tradeMultiple`, `tradeInternal`, and `printYieldOutput`. `trade` is called for single trade missions, `tradeMultiple` is called for multiple trade missions. Both functions call `tradeInternal` to determine the results of each individual trade mission.

`tradeInternal` will normally print out the hostile/friendly messages, but it can be passed a boolean value to specify that these messages should be suppressed, which `tradeMultiple` does. `tradeInternal` will return a null value if you get the "[Race] hate you" result, otherwise it will return the details of what you got. Even if the trade fails for reasons other than hostile relations, `tradeInternal` will still return an empty set.

`trade` will pass the results from `tradeInternal` directly into `printYieldOutput`, while `tradeMultiple` will gather the results into a set before passing them. Herein lies the determining factor for whether the "Your kittens return empty-pawed" message will be shown. If `printYieldOutput` receives a null value, it will effectively do nothing. However, if it receives an empty set, it will instead print the message in question.

---

Source: [Kittens Game BitBucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game/src/bca168edb77d8d164f6638d549ec82e16b707b51/diplomacy.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), lines 418 to 588 as of posting